# Cordless dremel hard wire

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply

4.8 v cordless dremel.  I've got a bunch of different supplies laying around all different volts none exactly right what would be most comparable battery = 4.8v-.7Ah.   Supplies I have close maybe class 2 input 120vAC,60Hz output  12vDC,400mA this is what is throwing me off.  I already figured out how to wire it in parallel or in series.  The other close. Class2 input:AC120V 60Hz6W. Output: DC5V 400mA.  So the 400mA is throwing me see what tall think an if we can keep it really simple not trying to change a bunch of resisters and capacitors or dip switches if yall could help a country boy out it'd be greatly appreciated.  Thank ya'll very much have a good day. And appreciate it again

Comment: We don't expect every post to be perfect, but posts with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read. They also tend to get read and upvoted more frequently. Remember, you can always go back at any time and edit your post to improve it. See [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: Converting battery powered tools to power supplies tends to be harder than expected - that kind of low voltage, high current design is really only suited for the intended batteries.  Granted this is probably on the lower current end as such things go, but it is still an off topic consumer product question missing the specifications required to address it in an engineering manner.  In contrast, line powered rotary tools are cheap.

Comment: Well thank you very much.  I'm poor, sorry to bother ya'll with such trivial things like you know trying to fix a tool my apologies for wasting y'alls time. Looks like trying to save the average American a little money by fixing a tool didn't really seem like a bad idea at the time. That's exactly what's wrong with alot of the people in this country right there. You know help thy neighbor.  We're all neighbors on this rock and can't get along for nothing because of situations just like mine all over the world that everyone almost breaks there neck not to see. Sorry for ur lost ⏳I

Comment: you probably need 5 to 10A to run that motor,  a surplus PC powersupply's 5V line can probably do it.

Comment: Chill.  What folks are trying to tell you is just that it isn't as simple as you'd like it to be.  You can screw around with things that sort of half ass work, or you can do it right.  The bits and pieces you have at hand fall way over on the "half assed" side.  Sorry to have to tell you that, but that's how it is.  Motors can draw a lot of current, and the voltage needs to match.  What you have at hand can't supply the current, and the voltages are way out of whack - like trying to start your car with a couple of flashlight batteries.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, not sure about the 18V drill, but I am running an attachment to the Dremel 4.8V cordless tool from a standard 5V 4A AC-DC adapter from a surplus store, for $5.95. It might be tricky however, the primary AC has to be first. A 5V 8A adapter runs the tool with no problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

The 4.8V Dremel motor has the coil resistance of about 0.5 OHms, which means that the start-up/stall current at nominal voltage (say, 4 V) goes up to 8 A. Therefore the power supply must be able to source this amount, 8 A, at least for a fraction of a second, just to start spinning.

A Ni-MH (or other) batteries have no problem to supply this current, while your 400 mA power adapter likely shuts itself down, or enters the pulsed regime - powerON, overcurrent OFF, etc.

You can add a huge capacitor to your supplies (something like 200,000 uF), it might work. However, keep in mind that the idle (no-load) current for the tool is 700mA alone (just took the measurement), so your 400-mA supplies are obviously too weak for the job.